# How to have <img> maintain er?

Tags: javascript

Would that be the right approach? If so, how should I implement it in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An elegant way of doing this would be to implement an `XMLReader` that can read the CSV file line by line (using a `BufferedReader`) to output the corresponding SAX events. Then use this CSV parser and the generated events as a stream source to dynamically build the XML result through an empty XSL transformation. This way everything will be treated as a stream and your program will be able to handle very large documents without encountering performance issue. Also, you'll show your understanding of subjacent parsing SAX standards and streaming concepts.

Here is a great example of this kind of implementation: http://mobile.developer.com/xml/article.php/2108031/Transforming-Flat-Files-To-XML-With-SAX-and-XSLT.htm (with a "properties" file as source instead of a CSV).

If performances (or handling big documents) aren't an issue, a simple `BufferedReader` that directly parses the CSV file line by line and creates a `Document` in RAM using `DocumentBuilder.newDocument()` will be a simpler way to get the job done "the DOM way".

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html

Here is a complete example :

SAXExample.java (the useful part of the code)

public class SAXExample {

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (InputStream is = SAXExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/demo.csv");
        InputStream transformerInputStream = SAXExample.class
            .getResourceAsStream("/echo.xsl")) {
      XMLReader reader = new CSVFileParser();
      reader.setContentHandler(new DefaultHandler());
      TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

      SAXTransformerFactory saxTransFact = (SAXTransformerFactory) factory;
      TransformerHandler transformerHandler = saxTransFact
          .newTransformerHandler(
              new StreamSource(transformerInputStream));
      transformerHandler.setResult(new StreamResult(System.out));
      reader.setContentHandler(transformerHandler);
      reader.parse(new InputSource(is));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static class CSVFileParser extends AbstractXMLReader {

    private static final Attributes EMPTY_ATTR = new AttributesImpl();

    @Override
    public void parse(InputSource input) throws IOException, SAXException {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(input.getByteStream()));
      String buffer = null;
      ContentHandler handler = getContentHandler();
      if (handler == null)
        return;
      handler.startDocument();
      while ((buffer = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String content = buffer.substring(buffer.indexOf(",") + 1,
            buffer.lastIndexOf("\""));
        if (buffer.startsWith("\"open,")) {
          handler.startElement("", content, "", EMPTY_ATTR);
        } else if (buffer.startsWith("\"close,")) {
          handler.endElement("", "", content);
        } else {
          char[] chars = content.toCharArray();
          handler.characters(chars, 0, chars.length);
        }
      }
      handler.endDocument();
    }

  }

}
```

AbstractXMLReader.java (utility class to simply implements an XMLReader) :

```
public abstract class AbstractXMLReader implements org.xml.sax.XMLReader {

  private Map<String, Object> featureMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  private Map<String, Object> propertyMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  private EntityResolver entityResolver;
  private DTDHandler dtdHandler;
  private ContentHandler contentHandler;
  private ErrorHandler errorHandler;

  public abstract void parse(InputSource input)
      throws IOException, SAXException;

  public boolean getFeature(String name)
      throws SAXNotRecognizedException, SAXNotSupportedException {
    Boolean featureValue = (Boolean) this.featureMap.get(name);
    return (featureValue == null) ? false : featureValue.booleanValue();
  }

  public void setFeature(String name, boolean value)
      throws SAXNotRecognizedException, SAXNotSupportedException {
    this.featureMap.put(name, new Boolean(value));
  }

  public Object getProperty(String name)
      throws SAXNotRecognizedException, SAXNotSupportedException {
    return this.propertyMap.get(name);
  }

  public void setProperty(String name, Object value)
      throws SAXNotRecognizedException, SAXNotSupportedException {
    this.propertyMap.put(name, value);
  }

  public void setEntityResolver(EntityResolver entityResolver) {
    this.entityResolver = entityResolver;
  }

  public EntityResolver getEntityResolver() {
    return this.entityResolver;
  }

  public void setDTDHandler(DTDHandler dtdHandler) {
    this.dtdHandler = dtdHandler;
  }

  public DTDHandler getDTDHandler() {
    return this.dtdHandler;
  }

  public void setContentHandler(ContentHandler contentHandler) {
    this.contentHandler = contentHandler;
  }

  public ContentHandler getContentHandler() {
    return this.contentHandler;
  }

  public void setErrorHandler(ErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
  }

  public ErrorHandler getErrorHandler() {
    return this.errorHandler;
  }

  public void parse(String systemId) throws IOException, SAXException {
    parse(new InputSource(systemId));
  }
}
```

echo.xsl (the "empty" XSLT transformation to only output the original XML as generated by our custom parser)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using this class with your example output the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><story>
<id>1234</id>
  <snaps>
    <snap/>
    <snap/>
    <snap/>
    <snap/>
  </snaps>
</story>
```

The CSV Parser is a "quick & dirty" implementation that does not really implements the full CSV specifications, but only your needs.

I think understanding these XML parsing and XSL transformation concepts were the goals of this exercise.

Comment: I took a look at what you suggested but still can't seem to figure out. Before I accept the answer and upvote, do you mind, showing an example of it?

Comment: There you go. Good luck !

Comment: Wow thank you so much for the in-depth info. Didn't expect it to be this complex. So this is basically the ground approach to solving it?

Comment: It is the right approach to solve it the SAX way, which works with streams. Working with streams let you handles a lot of datas without performance issue since very few informations resides in RAM.

As I said, keeping only the `BufferedReader` part and working with a DOM tree in RAM could be a much simpler approach (using `DocumentBuilder`), but it may presents performance issues if you need to work with big CSV files.

Please upvote and accept the answer. :-)

Comment: Got it. Will give it a try. Thank you so much Simon!